# Find sorting algorithm for an elevators floor travel schedule, starting from the current floor with preselected floors to reach and a travel direction

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm making an elevator in react, But I need to make a function that sorts an array to the nearest to the number X and also there is a condition if the elevator goes up or down,

so for example,

- There are in total 5 floors.
- X = Current Floor 3

You're now on floor 3 and click on the button **UP** and you click the numbers
**2 -> 5 -> 4 -> 1**

The array should be sorted so that it goes like this: *3* **-> 4 -> 5 -> 2 -> 1**.

Pseudocode:

```
let currentFloor = 3; 
let direction = "UP";
let clickedButtons = [2,5,4,1];

// ClickedButtons after sorted
 clickedButtons = [4,5,2,1]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where's your implementation?

Comment: And where does the information of the preferred initial direction come from ... as for the provided example ... **`3=>2=>1=>4=>5`** is as much a valid solution as **`3=>4=>5=>2=>1`** is, especially since I personally from the input sequence of **`2, 5, 4, 1`** had chosen the former over the latter precedence.

Comment: There are 2 Buttons with UP or DOWN to prepare the elevator if you wanna go up or down, then there are buttons for all the floors, you click on the floor buttons you want to go e.g you click on 2 -> 5 -> 4 -> 1 in that order, then it first should go up and go to the floors that are above the current floor then after that it will go to the floors below the current floor.

Comment: @Cedric ... 1/2 With this scenario the only sorting needed is e.g. an ascending sorting of all floor numbers ... `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` ... one find's the index of the current floor number `3` which is `2` ... `'up'` will be translated into direction vector of `1`, thus one takes 1st everything higher than index `2` or right from index `2` ... and 2nd everything left from index `2` ... result ... `[4, 5, 2, 1]`.

Comment: @Cedric ... 2/2 One does likewise for `'down'`/`-1` where one 1st takes everything left from index `2` and 2nd everything right from index `2`  ... result ... `[2, 1, 4, 5]`. There is no sorting magic since with the known preset of either `'up'` or `'down'` the floor travel schedule is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need sth like this

Whenever you go up, you need to find all greater numbers and sort them in ascending order so elevator will stop at the next possible floor as it goes up.

Then find all lower numbers and sort them in reverse order.

The opposite procedure will be done if you choose to go down.

```js
let arr = [10, 4, 8, 1, -2, 6];

let x = 3;

const goUp = (num, arr) => arr.filter(obj => obj > num).sort((a, b) => a - b)
const goDown = (num, arr) => arr.filter(obj => obj < num).sort((a, b) => b - a)

function printSequence(arr, initial, direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
    console.log(goUp(initial, arr).concat(goDown(initial, arr)))
  } else {
    console.log(goDown(initial, arr).concat(goUp(initial, arr)))
  }
}

printSequence(arr, 3, 'up')
printSequence(arr, 3, 'down')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the array into two arrays. One contains only higher numbers than the currentFloor other contains only lower numbers such as:

```
let lowerFloors = clickedButtons.filter(floor => floor > currnentFloor);
let upperFloors = clickedButtons.filter(floor => floor > currnentFloor);
```

Then sort each array lowerFloors would be descending, and higherFloors would be in ascending order.

```
upperFloors = upperFloors.sort((a, b) => {
  return a - b;
});

lowerFloors = lowerFloors.sort((a, b) => {
  return a - b;
});
lowerFloors = lowerFloors.reverse();
```

Then merge both arrays. If you going up upperFloors array would be first, else lowerFloors would be first.

```
let newArray;

if (direction === "UP") {
 newArray = upperFloors.concat(lowerFloors);
} else {
 newArray = lowerFloors.concat(upperFloors)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From both of my above comments ...

> @Cedric ... 1/2 With this scenario the only sorting needed is e.g. an ascending sorting of all floor numbers ... `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` ... one find's the index of the current floor number `3` which is `2` ... `'up'` will be translated into direction vector of `1`, thus one takes 1st everything higher than index `2` or right from index `2` ... and 2nd everything left from index `2` ... result ... `[4, 5, 2, 1]`.
>
> @Cedric ... 2/2 One does likewise for `'down'`/`-1` where one 1st takes everything left from index `2` and 2nd everything right from index `2`  ... result ... `[2, 1, 4, 5]`. There is no sorting magic since with the known preset of either `'up'` or `'down'` the floor travel schedule is obvious.

... but of cause one can cast the imperative recipe of my comments into a single sort formula.

```js
function getFloorTravelSchedule(
  direction = 'up',
  floorNumber = 0,
  floorTravelList = [],
) {
  direction = ((direction === 'up') && 1) || -1;

  function getTravelPrecedence(a, b) {
    return (
      (a > floorNumber && b > floorNumber && a - b) ||
      (a < floorNumber && b < floorNumber && b - a) ||
      ((a > floorNumber && b < floorNumber && -1) || 1) * direction
    );
  }
  return Array
    .from(floorTravelList)
    .sort(getTravelPrecedence);
}
const currentFloorNumber = 3;
const selectedFloorNumbers = [2, 5, 4, 1];

const upwardFloorTravelSchedule =
  getFloorTravelSchedule('up', currentFloorNumber, selectedFloorNumbers);
const downwardFloorTravelSchedule =
  getFloorTravelSchedule('down', currentFloorNumber, selectedFloorNumbers);

console.log({
  currentFloorNumber,
  selectedFloorNumbers,
  upwardFloorTravelSchedule,
  downwardFloorTravelSchedule,
});

console.log(
  "getFloorTravelSchedule('up', 3, [10, 4, 8, 1, -2, 6]) ...",
  getFloorTravelSchedule('up', 3, [10, 4, 8, 1, -2, 6])
);
console.log(
  "getFloorTravelSchedule('down', 3, [10, 4, 8, 1, -2, 6]) ...",
  getFloorTravelSchedule('down', 3, [10, 4, 8, 1, -2, 6])
);

console.log(
  "getFloorTravelSchedule('up', 7, [10, 4, 8, 1, -2, 6]) ...",
  getFloorTravelSchedule('up', 7, [10, 4, 8, 1, -2, 6])
);
console.log(
  "getFloorTravelSchedule('down', 0, [10, 4, 8, 1, -2, 6]) ...",
  getFloorTravelSchedule('down', 0, [10, 4, 8, 1, -2, 6])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: **NOTE**: This answer breaks if `floorTravelList` contains the current floor as one it's entries.

Comment: @AnonymousPanda ... thanks for pointing it ... wile developing, I was aware of it but this feature explicitly was not part of the requirement. There are at least two scenarios how such a case can be handled and the OP didn't even mention it.

Comment: @AnonymousPanda & Peter, Checkout my solution, it handles this scenario and if the same entry is present, it places it at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

We can think of an elevator having a state.  We can apply functions using that state to get a new state.  For our purposes, the state might consist of the elevator's current floor, the direction it's traveling, and the list of scheduled stops.

We're looking for a function that takes an elevator that's still, but which already has a direction chosen, and a collection of floors to visit; it should return the entire new state.  If we want just the list of scheduled stops, we can read that off this state.

We could build that off a function that calls an elevator to a given floor, just folding the list of floors and the initial state into a new state.  So `addStops` will depend on `call` -- which would be useful in itself to call the elevator to a given floor.

In either case, we will need to sort the stops to be made based on our current floor and direction.  So there is a function also for that.  Putting these together, we can imagine a design like this:

```js
const sortStops = (current, direction, stops) => {
  const floors = [... stops] .sort ((a, b) => a - b)
  const above = floors .filter ((f) => f > current)
  const below = floors .filter ((f) => f < current) .reverse ()
  return direction == 'UP' ? [... above, ...below] : [...below, ...above]
}

const call = ({current, direction, stops}, floor) => { 
  const newStops = sortStops ([... new Set ([...stops, floor])], direction, current)
  const newDirection = newStops .length ? (newStops [0] > current ? 'UP' : 'DOWN') : direction
  return {current, direction: newDirection, stops: newStops}
}

const addStops = ({current, direction, stops}, floors) =>
  sortStops (current, direction, stops) .reduce (call, elevator)


// our initial elevator state: on floor 3, headed up, with no stops scheduled
const elevator = {current: 3, direction: 'UP', stops: []}

console .log (addStops (elevator, [2, 5, 4, 1]))
```

This will return

```js
{current: 3, direction: "UP", stops: [4, 5, 2, 1]}
```

The advantage of this is that we can write other functions on this same data structure to perform other actions of the elevator, like making its next stop:

```js
const stop = ({current, stops, direction}) => stops .length
  ? {
      current: stops [0], 
      stops: stops .slice (1), 
      direction: stops .length > 1 ? stops [1] > stops [0] ? 'UP' : 'DOWN' : 'N/A'
    }
  : {current, stops, direction: 'N/A'}

const elevator = {current: 3, stops: [], direction: 'UP'}
```

If we call `stop` on `{current:3, direction: "UP", stops:[4,5,2,1]}`, we will get

```js
{current:4, direction: "UP", stops:[5,2,1]}
```

And if we called it again that result, we would get

```js
{current:5, direction: "DOWN", stops:[2,1]}
```

And then

```js
{current:2, direction: "DOWN", stops:[1]}
```

and

```js
{current:1, direction: "N/A", stops:[]}
```

at which point another call won't do anything, returning again:

```js
{current:1, direction: "N/A", stops:[]}
```

And we could write other functions -- maybe a `cancelAllStops` in case of a fire alarm.  The point is that we can work with immutable state objects with some simple functions.  In an object-oriented system, these would be methods on a mutable object.  Here they're just plain functions.  This can be a very useful way of structuring your data.

Answer (score 0):

- The list of floors can be divided into two group, one group contains all floors above the current floor & the other contains all floors below the current floor.
- The group that contains higher floors, always needs to be sorted in ascending order irrespective of the direction.
- The group that contains lower floors, always needs to be sorted in descending order irrespective of the direction.
- If the direction is "UP", then the higher floors group needs appear before the lower floors group.
- If the direction is "DOWN", then the lower floors group needs appear before the higher floors group.

```js
function getRoute(dir, currFloor, floorList) {
  return floorList
    .reduce((g, f) => (g[+(dir === "UP" ? f < currFloor : f > currFloor)].push(f), g), [[], []])
    .flatMap((g, i) => g.sort((a, b) => (dir === "UP" ? 2 * i - 1 : 1 - 2 * i) * (b - a)));
}

console.log(getRoute("UP", 3, [5, 1, 4, 7, 2, 0]));
console.log(getRoute("DOWN", 3, [5, 1, 4, 7, 2, 0]));
console.log(getRoute("UP", 5, [1, 0, 2]));
console.log(getRoute("UP", 4, [7, 9, 5, 10]));
console.log(getRoute("DOWN", 5, [1, 0, 2]));
console.log(getRoute("DOWN", 4, [7, 9, 5, 10]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

1. Using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) divide the `floorList` into groups and based on the `dir` decide which group appears first.
2. Using [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) sort the higher floors group in ascending order & the lower floors group in descending order.